# Kali Linux on Raspbeery Pi 4 - Keyboard/Mouse Not Work, Can't Enter Password

Tags: kali-linux, raspberry-pi, keyboard, mouse

Thank you for taking the time to read this. I have just installed the Kali Linux RaspberryPi 4 Torrent from Offensive Security and I flashed it to a 64gb MicroSD card. That went well and once I booted up Kali on Raspberry Pi I was brought to the login screen where I type Root - Toor as the login info, but my keyboard & mouse are not registering. I tried a wired keyboard & mouse and still nothing. I am so new to this world, that I may be running into something small, or for all, I know my USB ports could be bad? I can't type or move the mouse at all, that is the issue that I am running into. I really appreciate any help!!

Comment: If you're really new why not try [NOOBS with Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/noobs/)? Kali isn't a beginner's distribution.

Comment: I am open to it, I mainly purchased it to work with Kali, though I do want to buy some more to play around with.